# Prevent html from opening if already opened in another tab

Tags: php, javascript, html, google-chrome, tabs

I am new to this site.
I have Created an `.exe` Launcher for an `html` which opens the `html` with google chrome in Kiosk mode(full screen mode with tabs and address bar hidden).

Note: The Launcher has it's own copy of Chrome within its main install directory.

My problem is, whenever the user starts the Launcher, it points to the same Kiosk-Chrome but opens it in a new tab. Since tabs are hidden, there's no way for users to go back to the previous tab unless closing the new tab with "<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>" or switching to previous tab with "<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>" or "<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>".

Is there anyway to check if the same `html` is already open?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible from within php, javascript or html.
But it should be possible for your launcher to which webpage the existing chrome instances has open, at least you should be able to read the title of the existing tabs.

Other than that, when your launcher opens the webpage you should be able to specify a name for the window instance (such as the target of a href link). Perhaps your problem would be solved if you used that option to specify some cryptic window name, but which is unique to your launcher.

Comment: THANKS! I got it Solved thanks to Frederik's answer.

What I did:
Added batch codes to check if the program, Given the path to it, is Running.

Comment: You're welcome. Sounds like a solid solution - since you bundle the binary.